# Ограничение значения zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу задать в качестве максимального значения `zoom` 1, чтобы картинка при увеличении не вылезала за рамку.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document.body).append('<div class="div1"       style="position:relative;border:5px solid black; width:300px; height:300px;"</div>');
    $('.div1').append('<img id="img1" src="images/10.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin: auto;top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px;"/>');

    $(document).keypress(function(event) {

        image = $('img');

        var imageZoom = parseFloat(image.css('zoom'));

        var zoomPlus = 0.05; // Шаг
        var zoomMinus = -0.05;

        var Zplus =  imageZoom + zoomPlus;
        var Zmin = imageZoom + zoomMinus;

        if (event.keyCode == 43) {
            image.css('zoom', Zplus); //нужен maxZoom : 1, чтобы картинка не вылезала за рамку
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 45) {
            image.css('zoom', Zmin); 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: `if (event.keyCode == 43 && Zplus <= 1) `

Comment: все получилось, наконец я, типо, сделал сделал это задание, спасибо!
а почему не сработало
 image.css('zoom', Zplus, zoom Max: 1)

Comment: жаловался на двоеточие

Comment: как в примере
map:{
      center: true,
      zoom: 10,
      maxZoom: 18
    }

Comment: На здоровье. `('zoom', Zplus, zoom Max: 1)` - очень странная конструкция. Не знаю что под ней подразумевалось.

Comment: `{ maxZoom: 18 }` - это создание объекта, в котором есть поле `maxZoom` со значением 18. В примере выше же ни одной фигурной скобки нет.

Comment: ну тоесть, чтобы у картинки был максимальный зум 1

Comment: Тогда надо было написать так: `.css({ 'zoom': Zplus, 'max-zoom': 1 })`

Comment: image.css({ 'zoom': Zplus, 'max-zoom': 1 })

Comment: .css({ 'zoom': Zplus, 'max-zoom': 1 })
не работает, zoom не останавливается на 1 и вылазит за рамку

Comment: if (event.keyCode == 43 && Zplus <= 1)
а вот это решение супер, и простое и понятное,
но хотелось разобраться только почему через  
image.css({ 'zoom': Zplus, 'max-zoom': 1 })
не получается

Comment: а нет, мискузи, все работает, я туплю, спасибо, скинь код, я поставлю ответ

Comment: Какой из двух вариантов добавить в ответ? Или оба?

Comment: но вот, как можно было догадаться мне самому, 
 моя запись выглядела вот так
image.css({ 'zoom', Zplus, max-zoom: 1 })
и, естественно, не работало, жаловался на двоеточие, потому как отсутствовали кавычки

Comment: Тут важно помнить для чего и где может использоваться двоеточие в JS.

Comment: можно оба, оба ведь подошли по смыслу

Comment: это все есть в спецификации?

Comment: Да, в [документации по .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для запрета возможности выставления значения `Zplus` больше 1 можно использовать такой код:

```
if (event.keyCode == 43 && Zplus <= 1) {
    image.css('zoom', Zplus); 
}
```

Для выставления у элемента CSS значений `zoom` и `max-zoom` можно использовать такой код:

```
if (event.keyCode == 43) {
    image.css({ 'zoom': Zplus, 'max-zoom': 1 })
}
```